# Adding iOS resources on Playground

Tags: ios, swift-playground

According to [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/images#adding-ios-resources):

> IOS resources should be added inside the App_Resources\ios folder in
>   your app. You can use @1x, @2x and @3x suffixes to target devices with
>   a specific screen scale. Here is a list of devices for each scale
>   factor:
>
> @1x - iPad 2 and iPad mini (1st Generation) @2x - iPhone 4s, iPhone 5,
>   iPhone 6, iPad (retina) @3x - iPhone 6 Plus

However, if I try to name a file photo@1.png in Playground I receive an error:

> The specified file name is invalid. Only alphanumeric characters
>   (including "_", "-" and ".") are allowed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where are you trying to rename them? What steps are you following that lead you to this result?

Comment: @AndyIbanez I uploaded the file. I clicked on the three dots next to the file, Rename. Then I renamed the file logo@1.png and the aforementioned error appeared. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Xcode Playgrounds, you can use the following workflow to rename images to your desired format:

1. Press ⌘1 to open the Project Navigator
2. Drag your image into the Resources folder (it appears, but is blurred out as long as you don't have any files in it
3. Rename it to have @1x.png etc. at the end

[image]